# GWT - synchronous return of a method

Tags: java, gwt, rpc, gwt-rpc, synchronous

Ok, there isn't synchronous call in GWT.

But if i have something like this:

```
class XXX {
    Config c=new Config();
    c.doSomething();
}
```

and the class Config

```
public class Config {


    private static HashMap<String,String> map;

    public Config(){
        final ServerProxyAsync serverProxy= GWT.create(ServerProxy.class);
        serverProxy.getParameters(new AsyncCallback<HashMap<String,String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                System.out.println("getParameters: FAILED!");
                map=null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(HashMap<String, String> result) {
                System.out.println("getParameters: OK!");
                map=result; 
                 // RETURN NOW!!!!

            }

        });
    }
```

if the asynchronous call doesn't terminate I can't do `doSomething()`, because sometime the method is invoked before the map is initialized.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extends your `Config` class to take a `Runnable` or a `Callback`. Something like this:

```
public class Config {

    private static HashMap<String,String> map;

    private final Runnable callback;

    public Config(Runnable callback){
        this.run = run;
        final ServerProxyAsync serverProxy= GWT.create(ServerProxy.class);
        serverProxy.getParameters(new AsyncCallback<HashMap<String,String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                System.out.println("getParameters: FAILED!");
                map=null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(HashMap<String, String> result) {
                System.out.println("getParameters: OK!");
                map=result; 
                callback.run();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
class XXX {
   final Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           dosomething1();
       } 
    };
    Config c=new Config(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How  about `doSomething()` in `onSuccess()` ?

You can't use `synchronous call in GWT.`Even though you made it somehowits not a good practise

When you need this you have to do the stuff in the `onSuccess();` of your RPC call .

So, the best idea is to simply use the asynchronous method and  continue execution via the callbacks provided.You will end up with a  much better user experience, and a more professional appearing
application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, i can't put doSomething() in onSuccess(), because sometime i need to invoke doSomething1() and sometime doSomething2()...
Config it's a class that initializes some parameters of my application, and i need to use it for different purposes.

Comment: @nap.gab I think what you say is not an unsolvable problem. I have faced such problems developing GWT and I could solve them. Maybe you should ask a new, a bit more specific question with more details.